# Suddenly all Spring Boot Framework dependencies lost in my project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot.

I was adding new dependency to the build.gradle.kts file (mockk). And after synchronizing build.gradle.kts, all spring framework related dependencies lost.

What i did so far:

1. I did File/Invalidate caches and restart
2. Clean Gradle and build
3. Removed (mockk) dependencies from build.gradle.kts

But no fixing. How can I find spring libraries

Comment: did you try to go to clean you local maven repository? It is a ".m2" folder. Try deleting it and see if that's fixes anything?

Also see if you need to update any proxy settings?

Comment: I fixed it by downgrading spring framework boot version from 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT to 2.4.4 then sync it and all libraries downloaded. After I again upgraded its version to 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT and again it downloaded all the libraries. I don't know what problem it was. Is it from Gradle or IntelliJ Idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading spring framework boot version from 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT to 2.4.4 then sync it and all libraries downloaded. After I again upgraded its version to 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT and again it downloaded all the libraries. I don't know what problem it was. Is it from Gradle or IntelliJ Idea